# Commercial Map Controls?

Tags: google-maps, user-controls, bing-maps

I am not sure whether this forum is appropriate for this question. But, I am dying for this information. The problem is certain parts of Google or Bing Map licenses does not allow me to use their map services/controls.

**Is there any commercial map controls (atleast for U.S) similar to Google maps available?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain how the Google and Bing licenses prevent you from using them?

Comment: Microsoft and Google both offer commercial licensing of their mapping products; you just need to contact them for pricing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many mapping solutions available that you can use, but the big problem that you have isn't actually the mapping software, it's the map source data. This is where the licensing actually comes into play because you usually have to source the map data from somewhere, and even Google maps have to purchase this mapping from somewhere - they then pass the cost of the license on to you. If you aren't too worried about 100% coverage, you might want to take a look at the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) project which is an open source project aiming to provide geographic data.

Anyway, if you want free software and you are using .NET, you can always download [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/). For an online solution, you could look into [DeepEarth](http://www.codeplex.com/deepearth).

Alternatively, if you are looking to pay for a commercial solution, you might want to look into ESRI or MapInfo solutions.

Answer (score 0):

ESRI has many [products that perform similar functions](http://www.esri.com/products/index.html), on both desktop and server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [mapquest](http://apb.directionsmag.com/archives/2330-MapQuest-Rolls-out-New-API-with-Licensing-Choices.html) offers commercial licensing of their services & components.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps does have a [commercial version](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/), but it'll cost you.

Comment: User indicated they cannot use the too due to restrictions on the license. customer might be in a locale that falls under some sort of export control locale that would inhibit the use of the tool.

Comment: @MikeJ: User asked for a commercial version, and did NOT indicate that he even knew a commercial version of Google Maps existed.  The Google Maps API Premier would not have the restrictions on the license. (Read the link)